# How can i add ip address to print object and print, they are on the same wi-fi but i always get error code 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintformatter, uiprintinfo

Print from iPhone with ip address via air print

```
 let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfo.Orientation.portrait
    printInfo.jobName = "print Job"
    let textWithNewCarriageReturns = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br /> <br />")
    let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: textWithNewCarriageReturns)
    formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 70, bottom: 70, right: 70)
    printController.printingItem = text
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    guard let printerIP = URL(string: "https://192.168.1.54") else {fatalError("missing url")}
    let printer = UIPrinter(url: printerIP)
    printController.print(to: printer, completionHandler: {(controller, success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            debugPrint("Printing Completed.")
        } else {
            debugPrint("Printing Failed. \(error?.localizedDescription as Any)")
        }
    })
```

Printing Failed. Optional(\"The operation couldn’t be completed. (UIPrintErrorDomain error 4.)\")"

Comment: You will get a much a much more detailed error message if your replace `\(error?.localizedDescription as Any)` with `\(error)` in your call to debugPrint or something to that effect, the main point is to not use `localizedDescription`

Comment: i already did it, but i have the same error as localizeDescription, cant find anything about this, there is a similar question on stack but no answer ...